# FOSUserBundle doesn't translate with trans_default_domain

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I am setting up FOSUserBundle dev-master with Symfony 2.3 RC1 but translation is not working well. It comes by default with trans_default_domain in the templates

In the login template. It doesn't with trans_default_domain

```
{% trans_default_domain "FOSUserBundle" %}
<label class="control-label" for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
```

but using trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') It works

```
<label class="control-label" for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
```

What's wrong with trans_default_domain? need any extra config?

Comment: What is your accepted answer @dextervip ?

Answer (score 11):

Try to enable the symfony translation component. By default it is commented out:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, solved it by setting default_locale.

[image: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/translation/locale.html]

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, but maybe this helps:

in `config.yml` under `services` :

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl: 
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl 
        tags: 
                - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck with `trans_default_domain`.  Instead, I pass the `translation_domain` value directly via the form options:

```
class MyLoginType extends AbstractType
{
    ...

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'translation_domain'  => 'FOSUserBundle'
        ));
    }
}
```